# Can I extend the methods of an attribute to its parent class?

Tags: python, inheritance

I've created a new class that contains within it another data structure (a pandas DataFrame in this instance.

This class would have other attributes and other methods in it, in addition to the pandas DataFrame. Some of these methods are named similarly to methods in the DataFrame, e.g., `to_excel`, but do some additional things before calling the DataFrame method.  Regardless, the main constituent is this DataFrame. Therefore, I'd like to be able to use all of the other methods of the DataFrame, e.g. `getitem`, directly on objects of this class.

```
class NewDataStructure:
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()
        # have some extra attributes here that the pandas DataFrame doesn't have

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.df.__getitem__(key)

    def to_excel(self, writer):
        # do some extra stuff here that the pandas DataFrame doesn't do but use the pandas method eventually
        self.df.to_excel(writer)
```

Is there a way of extending the methods of an attribute to its parent class? Or, am I going about this the wrong way? Should the NewDataStructure be inheriting from the DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either override `__getattr__`:

```
class NewDataStructure:
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()
        # have some extra attributes here that the pandas DataFrame doesn't have

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.df.__getitem__(key)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        try:
            return vars(self)[item]
        except KeyError:
            return getattr(self.df, item)

    def to_excel(self, writer):
        # do some extra stuff here that the pandas DataFrame doesn't do but use the pandas method eventually
        self.df.to_excel(writer)

obj = NewDataStructure()
print(obj.ix)
# <pandas.core.indexing._IXIndexer object at 0x01FE7090>
# pandas' ix
print(obj.to_excel)
# <bound method NewDataStructure.to_excel of <__main__.NewDataStructure object at 0x005670F0>>
# NewDataStructure's to_excel
```

If we remove `to_excel` from `NewDataStructure` class, we will be using pandas `to_excel`:

```
class NewDataStructure:
        def __init__(self):
            self.df = pd.DataFrame()
            # have some extra attributes here that the pandas DataFrame doesn't have

        def __getitem__(self, key):
            return self.df.__getitem__(key)

        def __getattr__(self, item):
            try:
                return vars(self)[item]
            except KeyError:
                return getattr(self.df, item)

obj = NewDataStructure()
print(obj.to_excel)
#     <bound method DataFrame.to_excel of Empty DataFrame
#     Columns: []
#     Index: []>
```

Or inherit from `pd.DataFrame` (probably easier and the better way to go):

```
class NewDataStructure(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

obj = NewDataStructure()
print(obj.to_excel)
#     <bound method DataFrame.to_excel of Empty DataFrame
#     Columns: []
#     Index: []>
# pandas to_excel
```

If we add `to_excel` to NewDataStructure:

```
def to_excel(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # do some extra stuff here that the pandas DataFrame doesn't do but use the pandas method eventually
    super().to_excel(*args, **kwargs)
.
.

obj = NewDataStructure()
print(obj.to_excel)
#  <bound method NewDataStructure.to_excel of Empty NewDataStructure
#  Columns: []
#  Index: []>
```